# why the values of my copied dataframe also change

Tags: python, pandas

so here my issue :

```
# creation of dataframe 
data = {'animal': ['cat', 'cat', 'snake', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'snake', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog'],
        'age': [2.5, 3, 0.5, np.nan, 5, 2, 4.5, np.nan, 7, 3],
        'visits': [1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1],
        'priority': ['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no']}

labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = labels)
```

if I run the code below the values of the column priorty change for the dataframe *dg* (ok good) but for the dataframe *df* too, why ??

```
# map function 
dg = df 
dg["priority"] = dg["priority"].map({"yes":True, "no":False})
print(dg)
```

Comment: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use `df.copy()`

because `df` is a `DataFrame` instance and so an object and when you set it to another variable, in reality you point to one object with 2 variables and pandas does not create a new object

Answer (score 1):

That's because [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) dataframes are *mutables*.

> pandas.DataFrame
> Two-dimensional, **size-mutable**, potentially
> heterogeneous tabular data.

You want [`pandas.DataFrame.copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) to keep the original dataframe (in your case `df`) unchanged.

```
# map function 
dg = df.copy()

dg["priority"] = dg["priority"].map({"yes":True, "no":False})
```